# How can I repeat an animation across multiple objects in sequence?

Tags: animation

[image: Screenshot of my graph editor]

I'm new to animation in blender so this might be a simple solution, but I can't work out how to repeat this animation (once) in the order it was animated in.

The animation for each cube isn't complex, but, given how many cubes there are, there are a lot of different timings, which would take a while to re-animate. The black cubes rotate 180° and have a white face on the other side, so the image is revealed after all of the cubes have rotated. They individually rotate from the bottom right to the top left, some at the same time.

I would like them to, after staying still for a moment, once again rotate 180° so that the white side is showing, in the same order that they rotated to black (bottom right to top left). Is there a way to do this with a simple copy paste command? I've tried many of different methods of copy pasting the animation, and all of them either loop the rotating to black animation, while mangling the black to white part, or seem to randomly scatter which parts of the image are black or white.

Comment: did you check "animation nodes" https://animation-nodes.com/#get-started

Comment: @Sanbaldo I've not heard of that no, does that have the solution?

Comment: Well, I've installed it and looked at some of the nodes, but I still can't figure out where to start with this. Do you have a screenshot of what the node tree might look like? @Sanbaldo

Comment: there are many youtube tutorials like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3N8H8X-GJk, this https://youtu.be/eLspIv-KTYg or this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBOuigtl6s4

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found some of the tutorials useful, but I must be missing something. I'm now trying to, once the frame number passes 200, get the cubes to rotate. (although I need to add the number of frames before each one started to rotate somehow, so they all rotate in the same order again). But for some reason, when I connect the final math node to the combine Euler node, the number seems to fluctuate wildly, causing the cube to rotate over and over at high speed. This is my node setup: https://imgur.com/YkX7ltF